# How to show description for an id field from another dataset in SSRS?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2012, reportingservices-2005

I had 2 data sets as part of my SSRS report.  First data set had following columns: id, dept_id, fname, lname and another dataset(DATASET 2) 
return dept_id and dept_description from query.

When i'm display the records i need to show like below(rather than dept_id, i need to show dept description for each user record)

```
ID   DEP. Description First Name   Last Name
1    Science            Sam         William
2    chemistry          Adam        Tom
```

Can you please let me know how to write expression to accomplish this?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: It seems like something you could return in a single dataset with a join but if that is not possible have a look at the [SSRS Lookup function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210531.aspx).

Comment: Thanks @SMM. it helped to resolve!

Answer (score 0):

Posting Answer as per SMM comment. It worked!

It seems like something you could return in a single dataset with a join but if that is not possible have a look at the SSRS Lookup function.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210531.aspx